# Some problems no longer generate console message, but are surfaced in the issues tab. Click to view 2 possible improvements.というイシューが出ている

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-devtools

Chromeのデベロッパーツールで以下のメッセージが表示されます。

```
Some problems no longer generate console message, but are surfaced in the issues tab. Click to view 2 possible improvements.
```

該当箇所
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

この青い吹き出しの上にマウスを乗せると上記メッセージが出ます。
このマウスから手を話したり、スクリーンショットを取ろうとすると、該当メッセージが消えるので、かなりわかりずらいのですが、「クリックしろ」といってますが、どこをクリックすればいいのでしょうか？

関連しそうなものとして、
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68219081/some-problems-no-longer-generate-console-messages-but-are-surfaced-in-the-issue/68219158#68219158
を見つけましたが、下記の添付画像のような感じです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

エラー箇所（画像では詳細を伏せていますが）は見えましたが、これは、私が書いたJavaScriptが開発環境ではエラーになるので既知のエラーが出ているだけで、イシューらしきものが見つかりませんでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

下記画像で示した領域をマウスで縦方向にドラッグすると、出現しました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

出現後の様子は下記：

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]